# Finding command output with the highest number in substring

Tags: bash

I need to parse the output of a command and find the substring after the backslash (i.e. `app-v2.zip`) for the file with the highest version
In the below command output, I want to find `app-v2.zip` because `v2` is the highest. I know this takes a combination of bash commands but haven't figured it out.

Command output:

```
gs://artifacts/app-v1.zip
gs://artifacts/app-v2.zip
```

Desired variable value:

```
app-v2.zip
```

Comment: In your case simple `sort | tail -n1` will work, no? In other words, you probably need to describe your problem a bit better.

Comment: Why not `(for i in *.zip; do echo "${i##*/}"; done) | sort -n | tail -n1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for example `basename` to get the file name, `sort -V` to sort version numbers and `tail` to get the newest version.

```sh
your-command \
    | sort -V \
    | tail -n1 \
    | xargs basename
```

Answer (score 0):

If your output is already sorted as in your example, this is trivial:

```
variable=$(yourCommand |awk -F/ 'END{print $NF}')
```

- `awk -F/`: Use `/` as the Field Separator
- `END{print $NF}`: Print the last Field of the last Record (line)